# What's the highest possible amount of free Carry Capacity?

Tags: fallout-4

This question occurred to me while researching an answer for this one:

[What's more efficient: lightened armor or pocketed armor?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/247323/whats-more-efficient-lightened-armor-or-pocketed-armor/)

Obviously, for a given piece of armor, Deep Pocketed will give you the best gain - net or otherwise - in free Carry Capacity. But now I'm curious to know what's possible at the extreme end of the Sole Survivor's pack mule capabilities, and how that can be achieved.

Here, I'm looking to solely address what's achievable on a (mostly) permanent basis. Temporary effects from drugs or food don't count here. Boosts from gear or mods only count as long as the equipment is permanently available to the player after it is acquired. (I haven't finished the game yet, so I don't know if there's any equipment relevant to this discussion that isn't.)

Answers also need to account for the reduction in available Carry Capacity that is incurred from the weight of anything being used to boost the overall cap.

Comment: You didn't specify, so I'll mention this: you can modify your carrying capacity using the console. The constant unloading trips were killing the game for me, so I set my guy's capacity to just over a ton. The real limit then would be either the high end of the number type that they're using to represent the weight, or whatever your computer can hold if it's arbitrary precision numbers.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have the maximum value from a previous game in my answer. It's likely the same in this one.

Answer (score 4):

Below you'll find the best I've come up with. All the armor is from the basic tier. Heavier armors weigh more.

**Base Capacity**
150 lbs

**11 Strength**
+110 lbs

**Strong Back Perk Rank 2**
+50 lbs

**Lone Wanderer Perk Rank 2**
+100 lbs

**Army Fatigues**
Weighs 3 lbs, +1 to STR, for +7 to capacity

*Baseball Uniform or Dirty Army Fatigues would work just as well.*

**Fortifying Synth Helmet**
Weighs 3 lbs, +1 to STR, for +7 to capacity

*Fortifying is a legendary effect that gives +1 to STR and END. SE user MeesterTeem reports having found exactly this helmet.*

**Fortifying Deep-Pocketed Leather Chest**
Weighs 5.5 lbs, +1 to STR, +20 Capacity, for +24.5 to capacity

**Fortifying Deep-Pocketed Leather Left Arm**
Weighs 2.2 lbs, +1 to STR, +10 Capacity, for +17.8 to capacity

*Deep-Pocketed Combat Armor limbs also weigh only 2.2 lbs, and would work just as well.*

**Fortifying Deep-Pocketed Leather Right Arm**
Weighs 2.2 lbs, +1 to STR, +10 Capacity, for +17.8 to capacity

**Fortifying Deep-Pocketed Leather Left Leg**
Weighs 4.2 lbs, +1 to STR, +10 Capacity, for +15.8 to capacity

**Fortifying Deep-Pocketed Leather Right Leg**
Weighs 2.2 lbs, +1 to STR, +10 Capacity, for +17.8 to capacity

150 + 110 + 50 + 100 + 7 + 7 + 24.5 + 3(17.5) + 15.8 = **516.8 lbs**

---

**Notes**

I got all my information for this answer from [Nukapedia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_armor_mods). The information there isn't complete, but I'm assuming patterns hold. I updated the answer with new information at a later date, and the capacity changed by 0.2 lbs.

I'm not considering any kind of cheating or exploits, like using the You're Special book more than once. If you want to cheat, just use the console. According to the Carry Weight page on Nukapedia:

> Using the console command "player.modav" carry weight can be increased to a max of 20,106 lbs.

Nukapedia lists legs as weighing the same, but I've found that one of the leather legs weighs 4 lbs, and the other 2 lbs. I think it was the left one that weighed more? Gotta check that.

Comment: Lone wanderer perk lvl 1 = +50 lbs, Lone wanderer perk lvl 2 = +100 lbs

Comment: @vartec Good catch, let me add that.

Comment: It is possible to arrive at a base stat of 12 strength, as the "Your Special" book will allow you to raise past 10, if you use temporary debuffs to lower strength down from 10, before picking it up.

Comment: And actually, if @Iszi could comment on if they would permit bug abuse, this base strength should be extendable further with the duplicated "Your Special" book exploit.

Comment: @Timelord64 Actually, I do prefer a "clean" solution - no console commands, cheats, or exploits. But feel free to mention them after the main solution. That said, I think your "You're Special" trick (the one with the temporary debuff before pickup) is fair enough to be considered "clean". At the very least, it's not game-breaking like an "infinite reuse of You're Special" bug (a la Oghma Infinium) would be.

Comment: You can further boos strength by an amount with chems. Mysterious Serum grants +5 strength and if you buffout with other chems you can get another +3 to strength, for a total of +8 temp chem buff to strength

Comment: @Josh This question is looking for *permanent* (or, more particularly, non-time-limited) solutions.

Comment: @DCShannon I presume all the armor you're using here is standard quality, not Sturdy or Heavy?

Comment: You can get 12 Strength, if you invest 10 first, then get the strength bobblehead, then use the You're Special book.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily consider it a bug. The bobble head simply adds 1 point to the skill, and the you're special book simply adds 1 point to the skill. Neither of them state `+1 to Strength, as along as the current value is less than 10`. If they did expect that, then what happens if someone does not use either until they're maxed out? The bobblehead no longer grants the bonus it says it does, and the You're special book vanishes into thin air, without granting anything, which I would consider more of a bug.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you don't. I've successfully raised a couple of skills (Agility and Perception) to 10, then using the bobblehead, then using the you're special book to get 12.

Comment: @Zymus That's not consistent with what I've read previously, or the other comment on the topic. If you test it and find that you can use the You're Special book on Strength when you already have permanent 11 Strength, then I would be convinced.

Comment: @DCShannon The fortifying synth helmet is  definitely findable. I killed a legendary synth(possibly a strider?), and got one.

Answer (score 0):

You can carry an unlimited amount of items if you are willing to sacrifice the ability to sprint.

Take the rank 3 Strong Back and rank 3 Moving Target perks, have 11 Endurance and wear two Custom Fitted leg armor mods.

Your AP's will drain extremely slowly while moving but you can carry an unlimited amount of loot!

I am at 99 983 weight now and take everything I come across with me.